# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in InAirSignature.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv

I am doing a program with Emgu.CV in C#

and i receive this error when compiling

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in InAirSignature.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV.UI,
>   Version=2.9.0.1922, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

any ideas how to solve?
for my coding, a webcam is needed.
below is my coding.

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.GPU;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using Emgu.CV.ML.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.ML;
using System.IO;

namespace InAirSignature
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private Capture capture;
        private Rectangle roi;
        private Bgr redOrGreen;

        private const int NUMBERS_OF_FRAMES = 90,
                          NUMBERS_OF_SIGN = 6,
                          NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES = 3, // X Y Averange
                          FEATURE_X = 0,
                          FEATURE_Y = 1,
                          TEST = NUMBERS_OF_SIGN - 1,
                          NUMBERS_OF_NEURONS = 15;

        private const int frameHeight = 640;
        private const int frameWidth = 480;

        private List<Image<Gray, Byte>> imgGrayBuffer = new List<Image<Gray, Byte>>();
        private List<int> pointX = new List<int>();
        private List<int> pointY = new List<int>();

        private int[][][] pointsOfSign, distanceBetweenPoints;
        private double[] finalAverage;
        private int[][] pointsOfSignReference;
        private int[] distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest;

        private int[] classes = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1};

        private int resultMode = 0;
        private int recordSign = 0;
        private bool record = false;
        private int counter = 0;

        private Stopwatch stopWatch;

        private const string SYSTEM_MESSAGE = "System Message: ",
                             WELCOME_MESSAGE = "Welcome! ";

        Matrix<int> layerSize;
        MCvANN_MLP_TrainParams parameters;
        ANN_MLP network;

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////                              Form                              ///////////////////// 
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        #region Form
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            #region Initialize graph
            chartX.Series.Add("X1");
            chartX.Series.Add("X2");
            chartX.Series.Add("X3");
            chartX.Series.Add("X4");
            chartX.Series.Add("X5");
            chartX.Series.Add("Xtest");
            chartX.Series.Add("Xref");
            chartY.Series.Add("Y1"); 
            chartY.Series.Add("Y2");
            chartY.Series.Add("Y3");
            chartY.Series.Add("Y4");
            chartY.Series.Add("Y5");
            chartY.Series.Add("Ytest");
            chartY.Series.Add("Yref");
            chartX.Series["X1"].Color = Color.Blue;
            chartX.Series["X2"].Color = Color.Green;
            chartX.Series["X3"].Color = Color.Red;
            chartX.Series["X4"].Color = Color.Pink;
            chartX.Series["X5"].Color = Color.Purple;
            chartX.Series["Xtest"].Color = Color.Aqua;
            chartX.Series["Xref"].Color = Color.BlueViolet;
            chartY.Series["Y1"].Color = Color.Blue;
            chartY.Series["Y2"].Color = Color.Green;
            chartY.Series["Y3"].Color = Color.Red;
            chartY.Series["Y4"].Color = Color.Pink;
            chartY.Series["Y5"].Color = Color.Purple;
            chartY.Series["Ytest"].Color = Color.Aqua;
            chartY.Series["Yref"].Color = Color.BlueViolet;
            chartX.Series["X1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartX.Series["X2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartX.Series["X3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartX.Series["X4"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartX.Series["X5"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartX.Series["Xtest"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartX.Series["Xref"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartY.Series["Y1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartY.Series["Y2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartY.Series["Y3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartY.Series["Y4"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartY.Series["Y5"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartY.Series["Ytest"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            chartY.Series["Yref"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
            #endregion

            #region Initialize Neural Network
            layerSize = new Matrix<int>(new int[] { NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES, NUMBERS_OF_NEURONS, 1 });
            parameters = new MCvANN_MLP_TrainParams();
            parameters.term_crit = new MCvTermCriteria(10, 1.0e-8);
            parameters.train_method = Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.ANN_MLP_TRAIN_METHOD.BACKPROP;
            parameters.bp_dw_scale = 0.1;
            parameters.bp_moment_scale = 0.1;
            network = new ANN_MLP(layerSize, Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.ANN_MLP_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION.SIGMOID_SYM, 1.0, 1.0);
            #endregion

            #region Initialize camera
            capture = new Capture();
            capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, frameHeight);
            capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frameWidth);
            #endregion

            initializeData();  

            roi = new Rectangle(338, 2, 300, 300);
            redOrGreen = new Bgr(Color.Red);
            lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + WELCOME_MESSAGE;
            updateResult();
            updateGraph();
            Application.Idle += processFrame;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            capture.Stop();
        }
        #endregion

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////                             Button                             /////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        #region Button
        private void btnSign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            record = true;
            redOrGreen = new Bgr(Color.LightGreen);

            if (sender == btnSign1)
                recordSign = 1;
            else if (sender == btnSign2)
                recordSign = 2;
            else if (sender == btnSign3)
                recordSign = 3;
            else if (sender == btnSign4)
                recordSign = 4;
            else if (sender == btnSign5)
                recordSign = 5;
            else
                recordSign = 6;
        }

        private void btnPredict_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float predicted = predict(new int[,] { { distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[0], distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[1], distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[2] } }, network);
            string result;
            if (predicted < Convert.ToDouble(lblThreshold.Text))
                result = "Success";
            else
                result = "Fail";
            lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + "Matching result - " + result + ", value: " + predicted.ToString();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tbId.Text == "")
                    throw new Exception();
                saveSignReference();
                network.Save(tbId.Text);
                lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + "Saved";
            }
            catch
            {
                lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + "ID blank";
            }
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tbId.Text == "")
                    throw new Exception();
                loadSignReference();
                network.Load(tbId.Text);
                lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + "Loaded";
                btnVerify.Enabled = true;
                btnSave.Enabled = true;
                cbAuto.Enabled = true;
                updateGraph();
            }
            catch
            {
                lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + "Invalid ID";
            }
        }

        private void btnTrainNN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnVerify.Enabled = true;
            btnSave.Enabled = true;
            cbAuto.Enabled = true;
            trainNN();
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initializeData();
            updateGraph();
            updateResult();
            calculateResult();
            rbS1.PerformClick();
        }
        #endregion

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////                            Check Box                           ///////////////////// 
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        #region Check Box
        private void cbBinaryImage_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ibBinaryImage.Visible = !ibBinaryImage.Visible;
        }

        private void cbResult_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlResult.Visible = !pnlResult.Visible;
        }

        private void cbSign_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == cbSign1)
            {
                chartX.Series["X1"].Enabled = !chartX.Series["X1"].Enabled;
                chartY.Series["Y1"].Enabled = !chartY.Series["Y1"].Enabled;
            }
            else if (sender == cbSign2)
            {
                chartX.Series["X2"].Enabled = !chartX.Series["X2"].Enabled;
                chartY.Series["Y2"].Enabled = !chartY.Series["Y2"].Enabled;
            }
            else if (sender == cbSign3)
            {
                chartX.Series["X3"].Enabled = !chartX.Series["X3"].Enabled;
                chartY.Series["Y3"].Enabled = !chartY.Series["Y3"].Enabled;
            }
            else if (sender == cbSign4)
            {
                chartX.Series["X4"].Enabled = !chartX.Series["X4"].Enabled;
                chartY.Series["Y4"].Enabled = !chartY.Series["Y4"].Enabled;
            }
            else if (sender == cbSign5)
            {
                chartX.Series["X5"].Enabled = !chartX.Series["X5"].Enabled;
                chartY.Series["Y5"].Enabled = !chartY.Series["Y5"].Enabled;
            }
            else if (sender == cbSignRefer)
            {
                chartX.Series["Xref"].Enabled = !chartX.Series["Xref"].Enabled;
                chartY.Series["Yref"].Enabled = !chartY.Series["Yref"].Enabled;
            }
            else 
            {
                chartX.Series["Xtest"].Enabled = !chartX.Series["Xtest"].Enabled;
                chartY.Series["Ytest"].Enabled = !chartY.Series["Ytest"].Enabled;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////                          Radio Button                          /////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        #region Radio Button
        private void rbS_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == rbS1)
                resultMode = 0;
            else if (sender == rbS2)
                resultMode = 1;
            else if (sender == rbS3)
                resultMode = 2;
            else if (sender == rbS4)
                resultMode = 3;
            else
                resultMode = 4;

            updateResult();
        }
        #endregion

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////                            Text Box                            /////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        #region Text Box
        private void tbId_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                btnLoad.PerformClick();
        }
        #endregion

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////                            Function                            /////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void processFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = capture.QueryFrame().Flip(FLIP.HORIZONTAL);
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frameCrop = frame.Copy(new Rectangle(338, 2, 300, 300));   // copy a crop
            Image<Gray, Byte> frameBinary;

            if (counter == (NUMBERS_OF_FRAMES - 2))
                redOrGreen = new Bgr(Color.Red);

            frame.Draw(roi, redOrGreen, 2);
            frameBinary = ImageProcessing.getSkin(frameCrop);

            if (record == true)
            {
                imgGrayBuffer.Add(frameBinary);
                counter++;

                if (counter == NUMBERS_OF_FRAMES)
                {
                    while (imgGrayBuffer.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        Point point = ImageProcessing.getHighestPoint(imgGrayBuffer.ElementAt(0));
                        imgGrayBuffer.RemoveAt(0);
                        pointX.Add(point.X);
                        pointY.Add(point.Y);
                    }
                    pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_X] = pointX.ToArray();
                    pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_X] = normalizeSize(pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_X]);
                    pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_X] = normalizePosition(pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_X]);
                    pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_Y] = pointY.ToArray();
                    pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_Y] = normalizeSize(pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_Y]);
                    pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_Y] = normalizePosition(pointsOfSign[recordSign - 1][FEATURE_Y]);

                    pointX.Clear();
                    pointY.Clear();
                    calculateResult();
                    updateResult();
                    updateGraph();
                    record = false;
                    stopWatch.Stop();
                    lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + "Time taken => " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " seconds.";
                    if (cbAuto.Checked == true && recordSign == 6)
                        btnVerify.PerformClick();
                    recordSign = 0;
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }

            ibMain.Image = frame;

            if(cbBinaryImage.Checked == true)
                ibBinaryImage.Image = frameBinary;
        }

        private int[] normalizePosition(int[] position)
        {
            int min = int.MaxValue,
                max = int.MinValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < position.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (position[i] > max)
                    max = position[i];
                if (position[i] < min)
                    min = position[i];
            }
            int midPoint = (min + max) / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < position.Count(); i++)
                position[i] -= midPoint;
            return position;
        }

        private int[] normalizeSize(int[] position)
        {
            const int targetSize = 300;
            int min = int.MaxValue,
                max = int.MinValue;
            for (int i = 0; i < position.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (position[i] > max)
                    max = position[i];
                if (position[i] < min)
                    min = position[i];
            }
            int height = max - min;
            if (height != 0)
                height = targetSize / height;
            for (int i = 0; i < position.Count(); i++)
                position[i] *= height;
            return position;

        }

        private void updateGraph()
        {
            foreach (var series in chartX.Series)
                series.Points.Clear();

            foreach (var series in chartY.Series)
                series.Points.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_OF_FRAMES; i++)
            {
                chartX.Series["X1"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[0][FEATURE_X][i]);
                chartX.Series["X2"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[1][FEATURE_X][i]);
                chartX.Series["X3"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[2][FEATURE_X][i]);
                chartX.Series["X4"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[3][FEATURE_X][i]);
                chartX.Series["X5"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[4][FEATURE_X][i]);
                chartX.Series["Xref"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSignReference[0][i]);
                chartX.Series["Xtest"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[5][FEATURE_X][i]);
            
                chartY.Series["Y1"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[0][FEATURE_Y][i]);
                chartY.Series["Y2"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[1][FEATURE_Y][i]);
                chartY.Series["Y3"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[2][FEATURE_Y][i]);
                chartY.Series["Y4"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[3][FEATURE_Y][i]);
                chartY.Series["Y5"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[4][FEATURE_Y][i]);
                chartY.Series["Yref"].Points.AddXY
                               (i, pointsOfSignReference[1][i]);
                chartY.Series["Ytest"].Points.AddXY
                                (i, pointsOfSign[5][FEATURE_Y][i]);
            }
        }

        private void calculateResult()
        {
            int average = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_OF_SIGN - 1; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < NUMBERS_OF_SIGN - 1; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES - 1; k++)
                    {
                        distanceBetweenPoints[i][j][k] = DTW.Distance(pointsOfSign[i][k], pointsOfSign[j][k]);
                        average += distanceBetweenPoints[i][j][k];
                    }
                    distanceBetweenPoints[i][j][NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES - 1] = average / 2;
                    average = 0;
                }

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_OF_SIGN -1; i++)
            {
                finalAverage[i] = 0.0;
                for (int j = 0; j < NUMBERS_OF_SIGN; j++)
                    finalAverage[i] += distanceBetweenPoints[i][j][NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES - 1];
                finalAverage[i] /= NUMBERS_OF_SIGN - 2;
            }

            average = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES - 1; k++)
            {
                distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[k] = DTW.Distance(pointsOfSignReference[k], pointsOfSign[TEST][k]);
                average += distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[k];
            }
            distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES - 1] = average / 2;
        }

        private void updateResult()
        {
            tbResult1X.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][0][0].ToString();
            tbResult1Y.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][0][1].ToString();
            tbResult1A.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][0][2].ToString();
            tbResult2X.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][1][0].ToString();
            tbResult2Y.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][1][1].ToString();
            tbResult2A.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][1][2].ToString();
            tbResult3X.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][2][0].ToString();
            tbResult3Y.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][2][1].ToString();
            tbResult3A.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][2][2].ToString();
            tbResult4X.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][3][0].ToString();
            tbResult4Y.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][3][1].ToString();
            tbResult4A.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][3][2].ToString();
            tbResult5X.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][4][0].ToString();
            tbResult5Y.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][4][1].ToString();
            tbResult5A.Text = distanceBetweenPoints[resultMode][4][2].ToString();
            tbTotalA.Text = finalAverage[resultMode].ToString();
            tbRatX.Text = distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[0].ToString();
            tbRatY.Text = distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[1].ToString();
            tbRatA.Text = distanceBetweenPointsForRefenceAndTest[2].ToString();
        }

        private float predict(int[,] testingSetInt, ANN_MLP network)
        {
            Matrix<float> testingSet = new Matrix<float>(Utility.arrayIntToFloat(testingSetInt)),
                          prediction = new Matrix<float>(1, 1);

            network.Predict(testingSet, prediction);
            return prediction.Data[0, 0];
        }

        private ANN_MLP trainNN(int[] trainingClassesInt, int[,] trainingSetInt)
        {
            int numbers_of_training_set = 4,
                numbers_of_data = trainingSetInt.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;

            Matrix<float> trainingSet = new Matrix<float>(Utility.arrayIntToFloat(trainingSetInt)),
                          trainingClasses = new Matrix<float>(Utility.arrayIntToFloat(trainingClassesInt));

            Matrix<float> trainingSetPositive = trainingSet.GetRows(0, numbers_of_training_set, 1);
            Matrix<float> trainingSetNegative = trainingSet.GetRows(numbers_of_training_set, numbers_of_data, 1);

            Matrix<float> trainClassesPositive = trainingClasses.GetRows(0, numbers_of_training_set, 1);
            Matrix<float> trainClassesNegative = trainingClasses.GetRows(numbers_of_training_set, numbers_of_data, 1);

            ANN_MLP network = new ANN_MLP(layerSize, Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.ANN_MLP_ACTIVATION_FUNCTION.SIGMOID_SYM, 1.0, 1.0);
            network.Train(trainingSet, trainingClasses, null, (Matrix<int>)null, parameters, Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.ANN_MLP_TRAINING_FLAG.DEFAULT);

            return network;
        }

        private void trainNN()
        {
            // Getting the most closest signature
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < NUMBERS_OF_SIGN - 1; i++)
                if (finalAverage[index] > finalAverage[i])
                    index = i;

            lblSM.Text = SYSTEM_MESSAGE + "Sign @ no." + (index + 1).ToString() + " is the reference now!";

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES - 1; i++)
                pointsOfSignReference[i] = pointsOfSign[index][i];

            int total_training_data = 10;   // 4 positive, 6 negative
            int total_features_for_training = 3; //  dtw of x, dtw of y, width of sign
            int[,] trainingSet = new int[total_training_data, total_features_for_training];

            // Get the distance (x and y) between closest signature and the rest of signature into training set 
            // Feature 0 and 1 => dtw of x, dtw of y
            for (int i = 0, current = 0; i < NUMBERS_OF_SIGN - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i != index)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES; j++)
                        trainingSet[current, j] = distanceBetweenPoints[i][index][j];
                    current++;
                }
            }

            // Generate negative data
            int[] max_value = new int[NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES];
            int[] min_value = new int[NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES];
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBERS_OF_SIGN - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < NUMBERS_OF_FEATURES && i != index; j++)
                {
                    if (max_value[j] < distanceBetweenPoints[i][index][j])
                        max_value[j] = distanceBetweenPoints[i][index][j];
                    if (min_value[j] > distanceBetweenPoints[i][index][j])
                        min_value[j] = distanceBetweenPoints[i][index][j];
                }
            }

            Random random = new Random();
```

Comment: Well is that assembly (with that specific version) present?

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says.  The remedy is to make the missing assembly available to the executable.

Comment: better to add some code, so others can help you in better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project, right click on the References, then look for the Emgu.CV.UI assembly and select it.